# Two pages with the same title and/or meta-description within one domain

Tags: url, seo

Is there any penalty on Google rankings for using two pages with the same title and/or meta-description? If so, what is the penalty?

Both pages are on the same domain. One page URL is `example.com/abcd` and the other page URL is `example.com/uvwxyz`. The H1 header for both pages is the same, and both have the same meta-description.

Comment: Do you mean on the same website (domain)?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. The URLs are: www.example.com/abc and www.example.com/abcd (Content is different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Google would *punish* this.

Think of YouTube (which is owned by Google): The content of the `title` element follows this schema: `[user-contributed video title] - YouTube`. The `meta`-`description` consists of the user-contributed video description.

Now, there are probably thousands of videos with the very same title ("My cute cat") and some of them could even have the same description ("See my cute cat").

However, if a website consists of **many** (or even only) pages with same `title` and `meta`-`description`, it gambles away the possibilty for a better ranking. But when all these pages really have different content, it won't be *punished*.

Answer (score 2):

Title, Meta Description are among the signals which search engines uses to identify topic of the page and rank them in search results. Weight of Title is high in search rankings & both title/description are displayed in search results along with URL.

- As you have mentioned content of both pages are different, than by
  having duplicate title/description you are loosing some opportunity
  of targeting different keywords for search rankings.
- Having same title/description makes it difficult for both user as well as search
  engines to identify & differentiate between them.
- Even though there is no negative influence, but you are loosing on important signal (title) which can help in improving search ranking.

> Some ref reading on title: http://www.searchenabler.com/blog/title-tag-optimization-tips-for-seo/
>
> & duplicate content: http://www.searchenabler.com/blog/learn-seo-duplicate-content/

Answer (score 1):

There is not a punishment per se' it just isn't best practice to use. Why will you have duplicate meta information? Is the information the same on each page? Does it need to be?